# Akka Scheduler: How to get next firetime?

Tags: scala, akka, quartz-scheduler

we're using Akka to schedule some jobs in our Scala application. Is there any way to get the next firetime of an schedules task? I can't find a way to get these information.

I think under the hood Akka uses Quartz. The Scheduler of quartz can return the next firetime for a given JobKey. But I don't know how to get the Scheduler Akka uses.

Thank you
Torben

Comment: It depends on when your scheduler starts and what is the interval you set for scheduling.

Comment: Akka does not use Quartz.  Akka's scheduler is based on a Hashed Wheel Timer and AFAIK there is not any way to get the next fire time for a recurring task.  The scheduler is available via `system.scheduler` (if your `ActorSystem` ref happened to be called `system`).  Check out docs for more info: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/scheduler.html